# How to change the media query for the child element based on the device selection in parent element in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have created few React Components which has a set of styles that has been applied for the Desktop, Tablet and Mobile view which works fine.
Now i have created another Component which will show the created components to see how it looks in Desktop, Tablet and Mobile view.

Here is the implementation of the code

```
<div className={cx('responsive__outercontainer')}>
   <div className={cx(`responsive__innercontainer-${value}`)}>
     <StatisticsComponent />       
   </div>
</div>
```

Here the ${value} is based on the dropdown value selection (Desktop, Tablet, Mobile)

CSS:

```
.responsive__outercontainer {
    min-height: 300px;
    background-color: $color-concrete;
    padding: rem(94px) rem(72px);
  }
  
  .responsive__innercontainer-Desktop {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  .responsive__innercontainer-Tablet {
    width: 768px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
  }
  
  .responsive__innercontainer-Mobile {
    width: 320px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
  }
```

Statistics Component css

```
.statistics__container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  
    @include respond-above(sm) {
      column-gap: rem(24px);
    }
  
    @include respond-above(md) {
      column-gap: rem(32px);
    }
  }
  
  .statistics__item {
    @include respond-below(sm) {
      width: 100vw;
    }
  
    @include respond-above(sm) {
      max-width: calc(1 / 2 * 100% - (1 - 1 / 2) * 24px);
      flex-grow: 1;
      flex-basis: calc(1 / 2 * 100% - (1 - 1 / 2) * 24px);
    }
  
    @include respond-above(md) {
      max-width: calc(1 / 2 * 100% - (1 - 1 / 2) * 32px);
      flex-grow: 1;
      flex-basis: calc(1 / 2 * 100% - (1 - 1 / 2) * 32px);
    }
    word-break: break-word;
  }
  
  .statistics__innercontainer {
    border-top: 1px solid $color-black;
  
    @include respond-below(sm) {
      padding: rem(24px) rem(24px) rem(40px) rem(24px);
    }
  
    @include respond-above(sm) {
      padding: rem(24px) rem(24px) rem(48px) rem(24px);
    }
  }
  
  .statistics__title {
    font-size: rem(12px);
    line-height: rem(16px);
    color: $charcoal;
    margin-bottom: rem(8px);
    font-weight: $font-weight-bold;
  }
  
  .statistics__stat {
    font-size: rem(57px);
    line-height: rem(66px);
    color: $red;
    margin-bottom: rem(8px);
    font-weight: $font-weight-light;
  }
  
  .statistics__description {
    font-size: rem(16px);
    line-height: rem(24px);
    font-weight: $font-weight-norm;
    margin-bottom: rem(24px);
  }
  
  .statistics__disclaimer {
    font-size: rem(12px);
    line-height: rem(16px);
    color: $charcoal;
    font-weight: $font-weight-norm;
    @include respond-above(sm) {
      margin-bottom: rem(24px);
    }
  }
  
  .statistics__chevron-link .statistics__link-title {
    font-size: rem(12px);
    line-height: rem(16px);
    color: $charcoal;
    font-weight: $font-weight-norm;
    @include respond-above(sm) {
      margin-bottom: rem(24px);
    }
  }
```

Now when i run the application it works fine but when i change the device size to Mobile the media query remains the same (Desktop) which doesn't show the mobile view rather it shows the Desktop view since the Mediaquery for Desktop is enabled.

Desktop view

[image: Desktopview]

Mobile view

[image]

But the exact mobile view which needs to be show is the following which we can get when we resize the screen.

Correct View

[image]

I am aware that the media query is for the page and not for the element but i am not sure how to achieve a view similar like the Chrome Device Toolbar

[image]

It would be great if someone could tell me on how to achieve similar like Chrome Device Toolbar or if there is any better approach which i can follow up. I can't make changes in the styles of the children because it works in isolated way as well.

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to use flex and wrap when screen size decreases you wouldn't need to use media queries at all

Comment: @UmairFarooq Is it for the Parent element or for the child.

Comment: parent will be the flex-container & children will flex-items.if you want i can show you a simple example

Comment: @UmairFarooq Yes you can show that example

Answer (score 0):

Using [Display:flex](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/#aa-display-flex) & [Flex-Wrap](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-wrap/#aa-syntax) to wrap items when screen size if reduced.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.parent {
  background-color: gray;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;                /*it will wrap automatically when there is no space*/
  justify-content: flex-start;     /*items will be placed from the start (left=====>right*/
  align-items: center;             /*items will be centered within top to bottom */
  gap: 10px;
}

.child {
  width: 40%;               /*Big Devices Child Will take 40% width each to fit 2 children in a row*/
  padding: 1rem;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 771px) {
  .child {
    width: 90%;                        /*Smaller Devices Child Will take 90% width*/
    padding: 1rem;
    outline: 1px solid red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <h1>$100M</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In convallis elit venenatis mauris luctus lobortis. Nullam iaculis leo a mauris interdum, id vulputate ante viverra. .</p>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <h1>USD 750Bn</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In convallis elit venenatis mauris luctus lobortis. Nullam iaculis leo a mauris interdum, id vulputate ante viverra. .</p>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <h1>GBP $23,000</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In convallis elit venenatis mauris luctus lobortis. Nullam iaculis leo a mauris interdum, id vulputate ante viverra. .</p>
  </div>

</div>
```